# Get shipping country and remove product from basket

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I amend the current function to do the following:

1. **Gets the SHIPPING country from the checkout (for not logged-in users and
   logged-in users)** - instead of the IP address
2. **If any of the products in the basket match any in the array and the SHIPPING country matches any that are declared in the array it removes it from their basket** - instead of disabling the add-to-cart button

***Script*** - the current script gets the product ID,  and gets the users IP address, if they are in X country it makes the add-to-cart button hidden ... getting the ip address does not work 100%, often null is being returned and prevents the user form purchasing when they may in fact be in e.g. the UK and not be restricted to purchase said product ... hence why we want to change the way it works

```
function filter_woocommerce_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {
    // Validate product object.
    if ( ! $product ) {
        return $purchasable;
    }

    // Array of valid product IDs.
    $valid_product_ids = array( 4003, 6104, 4004, 12651, 12647, 12644, 12643, 12640, 12639, 12637, 12633, 12630, 12429, 12427, 11538, 11536, 11534, 11299, 11300, 11301, 11302,11303, 11292, 11293, 11294, 11295, 11296, 11140, 10573, 10554, 10505, 10481, 10237, 9379, 9377, 9375, 9371, 9368, 7756, 7023, 6101, 5952, 5950, 5948, 4791, 4790, 4786, 4784, 4780, 4778, 4775, 4771, 4767, 3268, 3267, 3266, 3258, 12300, 12083, 11632, 11594, 11249, 11088, 10964, 10966, 10967, 10698, 10692, 10417, 10179, 9598, 9593, 9333, 9108, 6049, 6047, 6045, 5017, 5003, 4936, 4806, 4682, 4677, 4673, 4671, 4663, 4661, 4650, 4646, 4644, 4642, 4622, 4444, 3252, 3249, 3247, 3207, 3202, 3122, 3110, 3106, 12318, 12316, 12313, 12311, 12309, 12304, 12006, 12007, 12008, 12009, 12010, 12011, 11944, 11945, 11946, 11947, 11948, 19494, 11950, 11936, 11937, 11938, 11939, 11940,11941, 11942, 11928, 11929, 11930, 11931, 11932, 11933, 11934, 11920, 11921, 11922, 11923, 11924, 11925, 11926, 11912, 11913, 11914, 11915, 11916, 11917, 11918, 11904, 11905, 11906, 11907, 11908, 11909, 11910, 11896, 11897, 11898, 11899, 11900, 11901, 11902, 11888,11889, 11890, 11891, 11892, 11893, 11894, 11880, 11881, 11882, 11883, 11884, 11885, 11886, 11843, 1844, 11845, 11846, 11847, 11848, 11849, 11835, 11836, 11837, 11838, 11839, 11840, 11841, 11827, 11828, 11829, 11830, 11831, 11832, 11833, 11730, 11716, 11702,11706, 11707, 11708, 11709, 11710, 11711, 11712, 11713, 11714, 11698, 11610, 11600, 11278, 10631, 10483, 10416, 10413, 10411, 10402, 10183, 10172, 10170, 10154, 10055, 10051, 9909, 9911, 9912, 9913, 9162, 9159, 9158, 9156, 9106, 7698, 7700, 7701, 6696, 5961, 4930, 4928, 4926, 4889, 4890, 4891, 4892, 4893, 4894, 4895, 4881,  4882, 4883, 4884, 4885, 4886, 4887, 4686, 4682, 4659, 4650, 4622, 4420, 3395, 3399, 3400, 3401, 3379, 3319, 3289, 3299, 3297, 3298, 3193, 3176, 13321,  12465, 12443, 12013, 12012, 11687, 11688, 11689, 11690, 11691, 11681, 11628, 11683, 11684, 11685, 11675, 11676, 11677, 11678, 11679, 11307, 11305, 11177, 10720, 10711, 10712, 10713, 10714, 10388, 10175, 10167, 10162, 10049, 10047, 9767, 9306, 8228, 8235, 8236, 8237, 7815, 7241, 7018, 7019, 7020, 7021, 7013, 7004, 7005, 7006, 7007, 6841, 6776, 6773, 6770, 6682, 6683, 6684, 6685, 6686, 6667, 6669, 6670, 6671, 6672, 6104, 5012, 4924, 4919, 4912, 4913, 4914, 4916, 4917, 4918, 4905, 4906, 4907, 4908, 4909, 4910, 4911, 4987, 4898, 4899, 4900, 4901, 4902, 4903, 4873, 4835, 4831, 4829, 4823, 4804, 4652, 4011, 4012, 4013, 4008, 4009, 4010, 4005, 4006, 4007, 4002, 3999, 4000, 4001, 3996, 3997, 3998, 3254, 1701, 1699, 13747, 13659, 13527, 13608 ,13609, 13610, 13612, 13613, 13614, 13615, 13616, 13617, 13618, 31619, 13620, 13621, 13622, 12369, 12367, 12365, 12348, 12331, 12329, 12327, 12325, 12320, 12033, 11965, 11974, 11967, 11968, 11969, 11970, 11971, 11972, 11973, 11506, 11394, 11395, 11396, 11397, 11398, 11399, 11400, 11401, 11402, 11403, 11404, 11405, 11406, 11407, 11408, 11409, 11254, 10961, 10933, 10936, 10938, 10939, 10940, 10941, 10942, 10943, 10944, 10945, 10092, 9490, 9494, 9495, 9496, 9497, 9498, 9499, 9500, 9501, 9502, 9503, 9504, 9505, 9506, 9507, 9507, 9508, 9119, 9117, 9115, 8453, 8456, 8457, 8458, 8459, 8460, 8461, 8462, 8463, 8468, 8465, 8466, 8467, 8468, 8469, 8470, 8864, 8857, 8733, 8734, 8735, 8736, 8737, 8738, 8739, 8740, 8741, 8742, 8743, 8744, 8745, 8746, 8747, 8748, 8579, 8642, 8643, 8644, 8646, 8647, 8517, 8518, 8519, 8520, 8521, 8522, 8523, 8524, 8525, 8526, 8527, 8528, 8529, 8530, 8531, 8532, 8533, 7110, 7111, 7112, 7113, 7114, 7115, 7116, 7117, 7118, 7119, 7120, 7121, 7122, 7123, 7124, 7125, 6540, 8357, 6541, 6542, 6543, 6544, 6545, 6546, 6547, 6548, 6549, 6551, 6552, 6553, 6554, 6454, 8358, 6461, 6462, 6464, 6465, 6466, 6467, 6468, 6469, 6470, 6471, 6472, 6473, 6474, 6475, 6446, 6082, 4570, 4518, 4550, 4551, 4552, 4553, 4554, 4555, 4556, 4557, 4558, 4559, 4560, 4561, 4562, 4563, 4564, 4479, 4469, 4456, 4444, 12475, 12302, 11944, 11945, 11946, 11947, 11948, 11949, 119450, 11936, 11937, 11938, 11939, 11940, 11942, 11928, 11929, 11930, 11931, 11932, 11933, 11934, 11920, 11921, 11922, 11923, 11924, 11925, 11926, 11912, 11913, 11914, 11915, 11916, 11917, 11918, 11904, 11905, 11906, 11907, 11908, 11909, 11910, 11896, 11897, 11898, 11899, 11900, 11901, 11902, 11888, 11889, 11890, 11891, 11892, 11893, 11894, 11894, 11880, 11881, 11883, 11884, 11885, 11886, 11871, 11872, 11873, 11874, 11875, 11876, 11877, 11861,11862, 11863, 11864, 11865, 11866, 11867, 11863, 11854, 11855, 11856, 11857, 11858, 11859, 11843, 11845, 11846, 11847, 11848, 11849, 11835, 11836, 11837, 11838, 11839, 11840, 11841, 11827,  11828, 11829, 11830, 11831, 11832, 11833, 11819, 11820, 11821, 11822, 11823, 11824, 11825, 11810, 11811, 11812, 11813, 11814, 11815, 11816, 11802, 11804, 11805, 11806, 11807, 11808, 11809, 11725,  11727, 11728, 11729, 11702, 11706, 11707, 11708, 11709, 11710, 11711, 11712, 11713, 11714, 11578, 11280, 11281, 11282, 10416, 10413, 10411, 10402, 10062, 9781, 9779, 9777, 9775, 9773, 9771, 9750, 9742, 9732, 9727, 9484, 8212, 7678, 7676, 7674, 7672, 7670, 7668, 4822, 4820, 4813, 4808, 4802, 4737, 4735, 4733, 4731, 4729, 2727, 4721, 4717, 4715, 4711, 4710, 4709, 4708, 4707, 4706, 4697, 3289, 10928, 5990, 12024, 12002, 7014, 7015, 7016, 6996, 4934, 4932, 4915, 4874, 4875, 4878, 4879, 4837, 4838, 4839, 14760, 6857, 6855, 14800, 15031, 3386, 3387, 5069, 5007, 5008, 5069, 7769, 5076, 5081, 5082, 5052, 5070, 5071, 5072, 3138, 15075, 15057, 15177, 3319, 12630, 14016, 9811, 9822, 9825, 3113, 15507, 15427, 15426, 15425, 15424, 15422, 15421, 15420, 15419, 3106, 3107, 3108, 3109, 13310, 16371, 16369, 16364, 16357, 16372 );

    // Array of valid country codes.
    $valid_country_codes = array( 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'CA', 'CH', 'DE', 'DK', 'ES', 'FO', 'FR', 'GG', 'GI', 'GR', 'HR', 'IM', 'IE', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'LT', 'LV', 'MT', 'MY', 'NL', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SE', 'SI', 'SK', 'US' );

    // Get current product ID.
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    // Only for specific products.
    if ( in_array( $product_id, $valid_product_ids, true ) ) {
        // Set default location empty.
        $location = '';

        // Geolocate location
        // External IP fallback and API fallback for the country both are true here.
        $geolocation = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip( '', true, true );
        if ( ! empty( $geolocation['country'] ) ) {
            $location = $geolocation;
            file_put_contents( ABSPATH . 'debug.txt', print_r( $location, true ) );

        }

        // For specific countries.
        if ( ! empty( $location ) && in_array( strtoupper( $location ), array( $valid_country_codes ), true ) ) {
            // NOT purchasable.
            $purchasable = false;
        }
    }
return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: this is a separate question , read the other post - you cannot ask two questions in one post ... as per the rules

Comment: Both questions have the same code snippets, so in that case, you can add points to the same questions and describe each point which you're trying to do with the same code.

Comment: Please remove the comment, the previous post has been deleted, we seek support in this question as we now understand the issues around obtaining IP addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip` for current user/visitor geolocation. You can also enable external API fallback which sends a remote request on IP Address API and fetch the user IP address You can also enable geolocation API fallback which again sends an API request using the IP address and gets the geolocation if you don't get the geolocation from request headers.

**Why your code had issues?** 
Since you're passing the IP address in that case `get_country_code_from_headers()` class function doesn't execute and if the external API fallback is `false` by default so if you're getting the wrong IP then you might now get the location correctly.

**How WooCommerce GeoLocation Class code works**

1. If you don't pass the IP address then it fetches the IP address and country code from Request headers.
2. Then if GeoIP API fallback(3rd param) is `true` then if you didn't get the country from then it will fetch the location from external GeoIP APIs
3. Then if External IP fallback(2nd param) is true then if you didn't get the county from the above steps then it will fetch the IP address from External APIs and then will call `geolocate_ip` passing the IP address which is a recursive call.

You can try this below code and check if you get the country or not.

```
function filter_woocommerce_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {
    // Validate product object.
    if ( ! $product ) {
        return $purchasable;
    }

    // Array of valid product IDs.
    $valid_product_ids = array( 4003, 6104, 4004, 12651, 12647, 12644, 12643, 12640, 12639, 12637, 12633, 12630, 12429, 12427, 11538, 11536, 11534, 11299, 11300, 11301, 11302,11303, 11292, 11293, 11294, 11295, 11296, 11140, 10573, 10554, 10505, 10481, 10237, 9379, 9377, 9375, 9371, 9368, 7756, 7023, 6101, 5952, 5950, 5948, 4791, 4790, 4786, 4784, 4780, 4778, 4775, 4771, 4767, 3268, 3267, 3266, 3258, 12300, 12083, 11632, 11594, 11249, 11088, 10964, 10966, 10967, 10698, 10692, 10417, 10179, 9598, 9593, 9333, 9108, 6049, 6047, 6045, 5017, 5003, 4936, 4806, 4682, 4677, 4673, 4671, 4663, 4661, 4650, 4646, 4644, 4642, 4622, 4444, 3252, 3249, 3247, 3207, 3202, 3122, 3110, 3106, 12318, 12316, 12313, 12311, 12309, 12304, 12006, 12007, 12008, 12009, 12010, 12011, 11944, 11945, 11946, 11947, 11948, 19494, 11950, 11936, 11937, 11938, 11939, 11940,11941, 11942, 11928, 11929, 11930, 11931, 11932, 11933, 11934, 11920, 11921, 11922, 11923, 11924, 11925, 11926, 11912, 11913, 11914, 11915, 11916, 11917, 11918, 11904, 11905, 11906, 11907, 11908, 11909, 11910, 11896, 11897, 11898, 11899, 11900, 11901, 11902, 11888,11889, 11890, 11891, 11892, 11893, 11894, 11880, 11881, 11882, 11883, 11884, 11885, 11886, 11843, 1844, 11845, 11846, 11847, 11848, 11849, 11835, 11836, 11837, 11838, 11839, 11840, 11841, 11827, 11828, 11829, 11830, 11831, 11832, 11833, 11730, 11716, 11702,11706, 11707, 11708, 11709, 11710, 11711, 11712, 11713, 11714, 11698, 11610, 11600, 11278, 10631, 10483, 10416, 10413, 10411, 10402, 10183, 10172, 10170, 10154, 10055, 10051, 9909, 9911, 9912, 9913, 9162, 9159, 9158, 9156, 9106, 7698, 7700, 7701, 6696, 5961, 4930, 4928, 4926, 4889, 4890, 4891, 4892, 4893, 4894, 4895, 4881,  4882, 4883, 4884, 4885, 4886, 4887, 4686, 4682, 4659, 4650, 4622, 4420, 3395, 3399, 3400, 3401, 3379, 3319, 3289, 3299, 3297, 3298, 3193, 3176, 13321,  12465, 12443, 12013, 12012, 11687, 11688, 11689, 11690, 11691, 11681, 11628, 11683, 11684, 11685, 11675, 11676, 11677, 11678, 11679, 11307, 11305, 11177, 10720, 10711, 10712, 10713, 10714, 10388, 10175, 10167, 10162, 10049, 10047, 9767, 9306, 8228, 8235, 8236, 8237, 7815, 7241, 7018, 7019, 7020, 7021, 7013, 7004, 7005, 7006, 7007, 6841, 6776, 6773, 6770, 6682, 6683, 6684, 6685, 6686, 6667, 6669, 6670, 6671, 6672, 6104, 5012, 4924, 4919, 4912, 4913, 4914, 4916, 4917, 4918, 4905, 4906, 4907, 4908, 4909, 4910, 4911, 4987, 4898, 4899, 4900, 4901, 4902, 4903, 4873, 4835, 4831, 4829, 4823, 4804, 4652, 4011, 4012, 4013, 4008, 4009, 4010, 4005, 4006, 4007, 4002, 3999, 4000, 4001, 3996, 3997, 3998, 3254, 1701, 1699, 13747, 13659, 13527, 13608 ,13609, 13610, 13612, 13613, 13614, 13615, 13616, 13617, 13618, 31619, 13620, 13621, 13622, 12369, 12367, 12365, 12348, 12331, 12329, 12327, 12325, 12320, 12033, 11965, 11974, 11967, 11968, 11969, 11970, 11971, 11972, 11973, 11506, 11394, 11395, 11396, 11397, 11398, 11399, 11400, 11401, 11402, 11403, 11404, 11405, 11406, 11407, 11408, 11409, 11254, 10961, 10933, 10936, 10938, 10939, 10940, 10941, 10942, 10943, 10944, 10945, 10092, 9490, 9494, 9495, 9496, 9497, 9498, 9499, 9500, 9501, 9502, 9503, 9504, 9505, 9506, 9507, 9507, 9508, 9119, 9117, 9115, 8453, 8456, 8457, 8458, 8459, 8460, 8461, 8462, 8463, 8468, 8465, 8466, 8467, 8468, 8469, 8470, 8864, 8857, 8733, 8734, 8735, 8736, 8737, 8738, 8739, 8740, 8741, 8742, 8743, 8744, 8745, 8746, 8747, 8748, 8579, 8642, 8643, 8644, 8646, 8647, 8517, 8518, 8519, 8520, 8521, 8522, 8523, 8524, 8525, 8526, 8527, 8528, 8529, 8530, 8531, 8532, 8533, 7110, 7111, 7112, 7113, 7114, 7115, 7116, 7117, 7118, 7119, 7120, 7121, 7122, 7123, 7124, 7125, 6540, 8357, 6541, 6542, 6543, 6544, 6545, 6546, 6547, 6548, 6549, 6551, 6552, 6553, 6554, 6454, 8358, 6461, 6462, 6464, 6465, 6466, 6467, 6468, 6469, 6470, 6471, 6472, 6473, 6474, 6475, 6446, 6082, 4570, 4518, 4550, 4551, 4552, 4553, 4554, 4555, 4556, 4557, 4558, 4559, 4560, 4561, 4562, 4563, 4564, 4479, 4469, 4456, 4444, 12475, 12302, 11944, 11945, 11946, 11947, 11948, 11949, 119450, 11936, 11937, 11938, 11939, 11940, 11942, 11928, 11929, 11930, 11931, 11932, 11933, 11934, 11920, 11921, 11922, 11923, 11924, 11925, 11926, 11912, 11913, 11914, 11915, 11916, 11917, 11918, 11904, 11905, 11906, 11907, 11908, 11909, 11910, 11896, 11897, 11898, 11899, 11900, 11901, 11902, 11888, 11889, 11890, 11891, 11892, 11893, 11894, 11894, 11880, 11881, 11883, 11884, 11885, 11886, 11871, 11872, 11873, 11874, 11875, 11876, 11877, 11861,11862, 11863, 11864, 11865, 11866, 11867, 11863, 11854, 11855, 11856, 11857, 11858, 11859, 11843, 11845, 11846, 11847, 11848, 11849, 11835, 11836, 11837, 11838, 11839, 11840, 11841, 11827,  11828, 11829, 11830, 11831, 11832, 11833, 11819, 11820, 11821, 11822, 11823, 11824, 11825, 11810, 11811, 11812, 11813, 11814, 11815, 11816, 11802, 11804, 11805, 11806, 11807, 11808, 11809, 11725,  11727, 11728, 11729, 11702, 11706, 11707, 11708, 11709, 11710, 11711, 11712, 11713, 11714, 11578, 11280, 11281, 11282, 10416, 10413, 10411, 10402, 10062, 9781, 9779, 9777, 9775, 9773, 9771, 9750, 9742, 9732, 9727, 9484, 8212, 7678, 7676, 7674, 7672, 7670, 7668, 4822, 4820, 4813, 4808, 4802, 4737, 4735, 4733, 4731, 4729, 2727, 4721, 4717, 4715, 4711, 4710, 4709, 4708, 4707, 4706, 4697, 3289, 10928, 5990, 12024, 12002, 7014, 7015, 7016, 6996, 4934, 4932, 4915, 4874, 4875, 4878, 4879, 4837, 4838, 4839, 14760, 6857, 6855, 14800, 15031, 3386, 3387, 5069, 5007, 5008, 5069, 7769, 5076, 5081, 5082, 5052, 5070, 5071, 5072, 3138, 15075, 15057, 15177, 3319, 12630, 14016, 9811, 9822, 9825, 3113, 15507, 15427, 15426, 15425, 15424, 15422, 15421, 15420, 15419, 3106, 3107, 3108, 3109, 13310, 16371, 16369, 16364, 16357, 16372 );

    // Array of valid country codes.
    $valid_country_codes = array( 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'CA', 'CH', 'DE', 'DK', 'ES', 'FO', 'FR', 'GG', 'GI', 'GR', 'HR', 'IM', 'IE', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'LT', 'LV', 'MT', 'MY', 'NL', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SE', 'SI', 'SK', 'US' );

    // Get current product ID.
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    // Only for specific products.
    if ( in_array( $product_id, $valid_product_ids, true ) ) {
        // Set default location empty.
        $location = '';

        // Geolocate location
        // External IP fallback and API fallback for the country both are true here.
        $geolocation = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip( '', true, true );
        if ( ! empty( $geolocation['country'] ) ) {
            $location = $geolocation['country'];
        }

        // For specific countries.
        if ( ! empty( $location ) && in_array( strtoupper( $location ), $valid_country_codes, true ) ) {
            // NOT purchasable.
            $purchasable = false;
        }
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Okay, I will attempt this and see if we still face issues how can I disable the add-to-cart button on search result and category shop view? as if we search e.g. PRODUCT A the button is hidden as expected on the product page, but on the search result we can click the add to cart button

Comment: I made a variable name usage typo. Instead of `$valid_product_ids` variable I was using `$product_ids` now I have fixed the code, please fix that in your code as well and test again.

Comment: still does not work, button is hidden when browsing in GB - a non restricted country

Comment: You can use this kind of code `file_put_contents( ABSPATH . 'debug.txt', print_r( $location, true ) );` for debugging and write the variable value in `debug.txt` file and troubleshoot what kind of values you're getting and what is not working as expected. `debug.txt` will be created in your root folder of WordPress installation.

Comment: Do i just throw this in functions.php? or before function filter_woocommerce_is_purchasable clsoing curly brace?

Comment: Use that line in between the code when you want to know the value of the variable which you're getting during the execution. In that code `file_put_contents` will create a file called `debug.txt` in which you're writing the value of `$location` using the `print_r( $location, true )`

Comment: okay, i did that, then went onto our website, onto a product that is restricted - remember GB is not a restricted country ... we are shopping in GB (UK), the log shows 

array(
[country] => GB
)

but the add-to-cart button is still being hidden when browsing in GB. I have updated the code in the question so you can see what I now have in functions.php

Comment: Removed the line of code, re added the line of code, it seems to work now when browsing in the UK - but this was the same behaviour with plugins and the previous code ... can you confirm if the button is showing for yourself? this product is one of the restricted ones - https://spsupplies.co.uk/product/evercoat-optex-super-build-41-primer-kit-4-7l/

Comment: Button is visible for me(`IN` Country code)

Comment: IN is in the array ... so this confirms the script simply does not work ...?

Comment: Ok, there was another typo `$location = $geolocation;` was wrong and should be `$location = $geolocation['country'];` I have updated the code. test it with the fix.

Comment: Okay, updated , please try your end see if button now disappears :)

Comment: Ok, found another logical mistake `array( $valid_country_codes )` should be `$valid_country_codes` only in `if` statement. try the updated code and it should work fine now. Looks like it's **typo** day for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250475/discussion-between-george-richardson-and-vijay-hardaha).